# ¿Cómo hacer un IF(X OR Y) en MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, condiciones

Quiero crear y definir una columna de una tabla de comandos (donaciones a mi aplicación) en función de si hay una u otra condición de un join (si la persona que me da dinero es un `Great Benefactor` o el dinero es de una campaña llamada `nuit`). Entonces intenté

```
        UPDATE orders
        INNER JOIN contacts ON orders.id = contacts.`Contact ID`
        IF contacts.`Great Benefactor` = true OR orders.Campaign = `nuit`
            SET orders.exclude_from_statistics = 1
        ELSE
            SET orders.exclude_from_statistics = 0
            ;
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
2021-07-07 20:05:53.674026 - creating column excude from statistics
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/etl/task/exclude.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/etl/task/exclude.py", line 23, in main
    add_column_exclude_from_statistics()
  File "/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/etl/task/exclude.py", line 11, in add_column_exclude_from_statistics
    c.execute("""
  File "/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF contacts.`Great Benefactor` = true OR orders.Campaign = `nuit`\n            SE' at line 3")
```

Pienso que me equivoco en la condición `IF contacts.`Great Benefactor`= true OR orders.Campaign =`nuit`` Parece que es muy pythonista

Aquí esta el script que utilizo:

```
from etl.utils.logging import info
from etl.mysql.connect import db, db_name
from etl.mysql.operations import add_column_if_not_exists


def add_column_exclude_from_statistics():
    add_column_if_not_exists(db, db_name, 'orders', 'exclude_from_statist
    info("creating column excude from statistics")
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("""
        UPDATE orders
        INNER JOIN contacts ON orders.id = contacts.`Contact ID`
        IF contacts.`Great Benefactor` = true OR orders.Campaign = `nuit`
            SET orders.exclude_from_statistics = 1
        ELSE
            SET orders.exclude_from_statistics = 0
            ;
        """)

def main():
    info("Column users.segmentation_2019")
    add_column_exclude_from_statistics()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es usar la función [IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if).

```sql
UPDATE `orders`
  INNER JOIN `contacts` ON
    `orders`.`id` = `contacts`.`Contact ID`
SET
  `orders`.`exclude_from_statistics` =
  IF(
    `contacts`.`Great Benefactor` = TRUE OR
    `orders`.`Campaign` = 'nuit',
    1,
    0
  );
```

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9b941245e3fd8ea7f07ae26095f9cc2a).

Answer (score 1):

El uso de IF en MySQL es bastante complejo. No has considerado usar en su lugar la función CASE?

Te quedaría algo mas o menos así:

```
UPDATE orders
INNER JOIN contacts ON orders.id = contacts.Contact ID
CASE
WHEN contacts.Great Benefactor = true OR orders.Campaign = `nuit` THEN orders.exclude_from_statistics = 1
ELSE orders.exclude_from_statistics = 0;
```